# Group Policies For Wallpaper Failing

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller

We have some computers that are no longer getting our wallpaper pushed by group policy. In checking to see if they can access the UNC for the wallpaper (\domain.com\NETLOGON\LogonFiles\our-logo.jpg) they are unable to do so.

I am 99% sure that this is due to an old domain controller (not the primary) that is failing. It is still on the network but it is no longer configured in AD Sites and Services for usage.

So two questions, is there a way I can check to see if the computers with issues are looking at this server still and second if so how I can force a mass change to force them to look at the PDC?

Thanks

Comment: If the DC isn't functioning correctly why haven't you removed and replaced it or resolved the problems with it? You're trying to fix a symptom of the problem instead of the source of the problem.

Comment: If you're 99% sure, then you can be 100% by taking out the old box. But from the small amount of data here, I'm not convinced that it's the problem, if it was demoted properly, then it would be taking part of the \\domain.com DFS.

Comment: I agree with you on removing the problem, and for several reasons we can't just yet (working on it with the network admin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you must do it this way you can change the SRV record priority for the failing Domain Controller. This article explains how to do it:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781155(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: And in so doing encourage client computers accessing the DFS namespace when looking for the wallpaper file to look at the old DC last.